# How can I use RethinkDB with EmberJS framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I'm new to EmberJS and RethinkDB. I'm using changefeeds of rethinkDB for user specific data to create web push notification application with emberjs.

I have created the same with nodejs and socket.io. it is working fine. I want to convert it to emberjs code. But when i tried to include rethinkdb in bower.json. Im getting a message "Package RethinkDB not found".

```
"rethinkdb": "~2.0.0"
```

[image]

The below is my working code for Nodejs with Socket.io and RethinkDB

server.js

```
var sockio = require("socket.io");
var app = require("express")();
var r = require("rethinkdb");
var http = require('http');

var io = sockio.listen(app.listen(3000), {log: false});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/home.html');
});



r.connect({host: 'localhost', port: 28015})
.then(function(conn){return r.db('my_db').table('user_feeds').changes().run(conn);})
.then(function(cursor){cursor.each(function(err, data) {         
    io.emit('feeds', data);  
    console.log("after Data >>>>>\n"+JSON.stringify(data));
});});

console.log("server started @ http://127.0.0.1:3000/");
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Asset Tracker</title>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
var socket = io.connect();
socket.on("feeds", function(data) {  
  document.getElementById("feeds").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);

});
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="feeds"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the above code to be migrated to emberJS. As I'am new to ember I find it difficult to migrate. Not much of a code sample available for rethinkdb with emberjs online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your client side code doesn't contain RethinkDB specific code you should look for socket.io for ember. There are several implementations for emberjs.

There is no rethinkdb package published in bower. There is a npm package which you can use in the browser as well.

Comment: if i include rethinkdb as npm package and and on emberjs-cli-build.js if i make it global, is it possible to use it across ember app?

Comment: you are right. there is no support for bower. and i tried to import rethinkdb drivers with npm install and it wont because it was written on nodejs method which ember-cli wont support.